# Checking for a string in array and add

Tags: php, arrays

How can i check if a string is already present withing an array before adding to it in php?

say if array is `$value`

```
$value[0]="hi";
$value[1]="hello"; 
$value[2]="wat";
```

I want to check if value exists in it before adding it to it.

Comment: do you imply if "hi" was present before, it will not be inserted again?

Comment: Using your exact words: "How can i check if a string is already present withing an array before adding to it in php?" comes up with the manual for `in_array()` as the [first hit in google](http://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+i+check+if+a+string+is+already+present+withing+an+array+before+adding+to+it+in+php). -1 For the "no research effort" clause

Comment: @stereorog: Then that needs to be explicitly specified, at least that OP knows that the function exists but is not what he wants - look at the current answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s='hi';
if (!in_array($s, $value)) {
    $value[]=$s;
}
```

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.in-array.php) checks if that value (1st parameter) is in the array (2nd parameter), returns boolean (`!` negates it)
- `$value[]=$s` will add the value to the array with the next index

---

There is another tricky way if you want to add a bunch of values into an array, but only if they are not there yet. You just have to organize these new values into another array and use a combination of `array_merge()` and `array_diff()`:

```
//your original array:
$values=array('hello', 'xy', 'fos', 'hi');
//the values you want to add if they are not in the array yet:
$values_to_add=array('hi', 'hello', 'retek');

$values=array_merge($values, array_diff($values_to_add, $values));
//$values becomes: hello, xy, fos, hi, retek
```

Comment: Needs a `!` before `in_array`

Comment: should be `if(!in_array(...))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in_array($searchstring, $array)`

`in_array("hello", $value)` returns true

`in_array("hllo", $value)` returns false

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if(in_array("hello", $value)) { // needle in haystack
   return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - Checks if a value exists in an array.

In case of `in_array($searchstring, $array)`, remember, the comparison is done in a ***case-sensitive*** manner, if the `$searchstring` is a "String"

**Example :**

```
 - in_array("wat", $value) returns true
 - in_array("what", $value) returns false.

 // Observe carefully
 - in_array("WAT", $value) returns false.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to create a [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29), it's much better to use array keys instead of values. Simply use

```
$values["whatever"] = 1;
```

to add a value, no need to check anything.

Comment: This is not quite the same in the current context, it means you must use keys instead of values. OP said he wants to check values. This also doesn't "check" anything, so is not useful for any situation where we would need to do so, and especially in situations where the keys are not explicitly indexed, i.e. `array('apple', 'orange', 'banana')`.